# Arduino strings and chars and pointers and such

Tags: c, arrays, char, arduino

I am finding myself again confused by C strings, chars, etc.

Here is some code I am using to test the syntax on the Arduino. I know that (*message)buff will give me a pointer (I still don’t really know why I need to use pointers, but I can do some research on that!), I convert the *message_buff to a String (just for something to do, but note that later on when I try and print this string to serial I only get a single 'c' character).

I set an array pointer three elements long (three bytes long?? I don't really know):

```
char *mqtt_command[3] = {};
```

And later on when I try and add a value to the array using:

```
*mqtt_command[i] = str;
```

I get the error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'

If I change that to:

```
mqtt_command[i] = str;
```

(without the *) it compiles fine. I don't know why...

Here is my code:

```
char *message_buff = "command:range:1";
char *str;
String msgString = String(*message_buff);
char *mqtt_command[3] = {};
int i = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);

  while ((str = strtok_r(message_buff, ":", &message_buff)) != NULL)
  {
    Serial.println(str);
    mqtt_command[i] = str;
    i++;
  }

  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("Command: ");
  Serial.println(mqtt_command[1]);

  Serial.print("MQTT string: ");
  Serial.println(msgString);
}

void loop()
{
  // Do something here later
}
```

And here is the output:

```
command
range
1
Command: range
MQTT string: c
```

How can I understand chars, strings, pointers, and char arrays? Where can I go for a good all round tutorial on the topic?

I am passing in a command string (I think it is a string, maybe it is a char array????) via MQTT, and the message is:

```
command:range:1
```

I am trying to build a little protocol to do things on the Arduino when an MQTT message is received. I can handle the MQTT callbacks fine, that not the problem. The issue is that I don't really understand C strings and chars. I would like to be able to handle commands like:

```
command:range:0
command:digital:8
read:sensor:2
```

etc.

Comment: Get and read a good book on C.

Comment: Learn C on a real computer before trying to understand the extra complexities of working on a a Harvard-architecture microcontroller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a C (and/or C++) primer first, you need to work more on your understanding of the declarations and the syntax for pointer access and so on.

This:

```
char *mqtt_command[3] = {};
```

means "`mqtt_command` is an array of 3 `char *`", i.e. three pointers to characters. Since strings are represented as pointers to characters, this can be called "an array of three strings". There's no actual *space* for the characters themselves though, so this is not enough to work with but it's a good start.

Then, your first error is this code:

```
*mqtt_command[i] = str;
```

The problem the compiler is complaining about is that you're dereferencing things too many times. Just `mqtt_command[i]` is enough, that evaluates to the i:th value of the array, which has type `char *`. Then, your initial asterisk *dereferences* that pointer, meaning the type of the left-hand expression is now `char`, i.e. it's a single character. You can't assign a pointer into a character, it (typically) won't fit.

Drop the initial asterisk to solve this.

To analyze further, this:

```
char *message_buff = "command:range:1";
String msgString = String(*message_buff);
```

is also wrong, for the same reason. You're dereferencing the `message_buff` pointer, so the argument to the `String()` constructor is merely the first character, i.e. `c`. Again, drop the initial asterisk, you mean:

```
String msgString = String(message_buf);
```

which can be written as just:

```
String msgString(message_buf);
```

Comment: Much appreciated - do you have any pointers (no pun intended) for a good solid C primer ?

Comment: For quick C intro (especially arrays/string/chars) I would recommend "Head First C" http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-C-David-Griffiths/dp/1449399916/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1358765927&sr=8-1&keywords=head+first+c

Comment: Ok cool - I have read other Head First books and they are very good. I will give that one a go.

Comment: I would also recommend Harbison & Steele's [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com/) as a companion reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
mqtt_command[i] = str;
```

This will work, as `mqtt_command[i]` is already char pointer. `*` will redirect it to any previously allocated memory, which is not done in the code.